# How i can pull all data project production to local enviroment in supabase

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I have created a project using supabase platform directly and not in local enviroment so all tables are in production, but now i need a local enviroment for development o test so i created a local project using this guide but the project is from scracth, the question is ¿how i can pull all tables from production to local enviroment?

[Local guide](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/local-development)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using pgdump to export the table schema and importing it back into your local environment. You can follow this guide https://supabase.com/docs/guides/platform/migrating-and-upgrading-projects

Comment: seems the anchor isn't there anymore? was wondering if there's a cli command or something. It seems that once you create a DB via the Web UI there's no straightforward way to replicate it on localhost...

Comment: I've updated the link on the original answer.

Comment: I used dbeaver !

Comment: Does this migrate your cloud functions and such, too?

Answer (score 1):

supabase db pull only will download the db as migration file then you need to apply it by command supabase db reset.